# How to map an array of data definition and an array of Raw Datas in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-pipe

Let's say I have these 2 arrays

```
languages : [{langId: 8, text: "Australia"}, {langId: 3, text: "English"}, {langId: 6, text: "English (UK)"}]

productText : [{langId:8, productName: "Product Name AU"}, {langId:3, productName: "Product Name EN"}, {langId:6, productName: "Product Name UK"} ]
```

On rendering, I would like to map the langId from productText to languages (Text)

**The result should look like this**
**LangID | LangName | ProductName** 

8 : Australia : Product Name AU 
3 : English : Product Name EN 
6 : English (UK) : Product Name UK

how to perform this kind of mapping in the template.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand entirely. Are they in the same order? Meaning that each element has it's corresponding element in the same index in the 2nd array? And also the langId is not relevant in this part, right?

Comment: Hi I mean. I have 2 list. One is a list of all the available languages. Then when I want to print out each Product Text, instead of display the langId value, I want to display his language name. If it's langID 8: I should display Australia as the language name

Comment: I updated the question. maybe it will help you to figure it out. Sorry for my bad english thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% sure I fully understand you. 
But assuming the order is preserved (meaning both arrays will have the same length, with the same langId ordering) then you can do it purely on the template like the following :

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let lang of languages;let i = index;">
    {{lang.langId}} : {{lang.text}} : {{productText[i].productName}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

If your arrays are not of the same order, you'll have to do some logic in the table file (as far as I can think)